# Wordpress Posts Multi Author without using plugin

Tags: author

I am trying to code a PHP page which I can allow multiple authors for posts.

At first I have my `pageAuthors.php` page, it allows me to choose my post and check for available authors. It is a simple form with an action that redirects it to a page `showAuthors.php`.

After being on `showAuthors.php`, you'll have the post you choosed and the available authors in a checkbox with the publisher automatically checked.

You can check other authors for being co-authors.

Everything is okay but I dont know the query I should write to access different tables in the database.

I searched and found that I should at first:

- Register a taxonomy using an array.
- Update post count for published users.

`pageAuthors.php`

[image]

`showAuthors.php`

[image]

All I need is the query to make give access to the other author to the and let him edit it.

---

***Some useful links:***

[Where is Author Data Stored in the Database?](https://publishpress.com/knowledge-base/authors-data-backup/)

[Where are WordPress Users and Permissions Stored in the Database?](https://publishpress.com/blog/where-are-wordpress-permissions-capabilities-in-the-database/)

Comment: "to access different tables in the database" - which different tables? How are you planning to store the extra author IDs? Wouldn't it just be post meta, which you can read and write with the normal WordPress functions, or are you planning something else?

Comment: And I really would just use an existing plugin to do this - they've solved all of these problems already. Why don't you want to do that?